# hadoop WordCount program gets stuck and doesn't finish runnig

Tags: hadoop

I have configured hadoop on windows10. When I try to run [WordCount](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount) program it doesn't finish the job:
[image]

What can I do to fix it?

Note: I have made a little change to the original program; input and output files are compiled with the code and don't need to be provided as arguments.

Comment: Open the `url to track the job` listed on the terminal. Go look at YARN

Comment: @cricket_007 YarnApplicationState:  ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.

Comment: `waiting for AM container to be allocated`. The ApplicationMaster container cannot be started, so one possibility is memory issues.

Comment: Ok. any solutions for that?

Comment: I found the problem and it was ridiculous: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28724329/4314810

Comment: Well, yeah. HDFS disk space is precious. You should setup Ambari to get metrics to monitor your environment better.

Comment: Take a look at yarn resource manager log to see why app master container could not be allocated.